# Transactions in WebLogic OSGi

Tags: jpa, transactions, osgi, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am building a web application deployed in WebLogic which also uses a number of OSGi modules, deployed in the WebLogic OSGi (Felix) during the deployment of my web application.

According to [WebLogic's OSGi documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/osgi.htm) I can choose to expose any datasources I create in WebLogic inside the OSGi in order to use them from my bundles. I have therefore created a datasource and used a persistence.xml in my OSGi bundle to look it up and inject (with Blueprint) an EntityManager in my OSGi service to use it. The configuration of my OSGi bundle looks like this:

**persistence.xml:**

```
<persistence-unit name="mypu" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>osgi:service/jdbc/test</jta-data-source>

        <class>com.test.impl.model.TestEntity</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

**blueprint.xml**

```
<bean id="TestServiceImpl" class="com.test.impl.TestServiceImpl">
        <jpa:context property="em" unitname="mypu" />
        <tx:transaction method="*" value="Required" />
</bean>
<service id="TestService" ref="TestServiceImpl"
        interface="com.test.api.TestService" />
```

I have also deployed in the OSGi Aries blueprint, Aries JPA, Aries transaction and OpenJPA.

My problem is that although this configuration correctly injects the EntityManager in my service and I can use it to read data from the DB, it does not create a transaction around my service methods and therefore I cannot write data to the DB.

I understand that the problem is that Aries transaction listens for implementations of `javax.sql.XADataSource` which it then wraps in a `XADataSourceEnlistingWrapper` and exposes as `javax.sql.DataSource` in order to be used by my bundle. In my case however the datasource WebLogic creates is a `weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource` which does not implement `javax.sql.XADataSource` so Aries doesn't pick it up.

Is my understanding of the problem correct? What do I need to do in order to have XA transactions in WebLogic's OSGi?

**EDIT:**
I am still unable to use transactions in my OSGi bundle unless if I call the OSGi service in an already existing transaction, started from my web application, in which the web application also writes data to the DB. In that case the OSGi service is correctly enlisted in the transaction and the data persisted. This is however not a solution to my problem since I can't really be writing data to the DB from my web application every time I make an OSGi service call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason changing the persistence provider from OpenJPA to Hibernate solved the problem. In order to use Hibernate (4.2.15) as a persistence provider the following modifications to my setup were required:

1. Include the following packages as DynamicImport-Package: `org.hibernate.proxy,javassist.util.proxy,weblogic.jndi` The first two are required for Hibernate's dynamic enhancement, while the third one seems to be required when using Hibernate 4.2.x in WebLogic's OSGi (it is not required if using Hibernate 4.3.x), however at this point I am not entirely sure why.
2. Use Aries JPA container 1.0.1 in order to overcome [this Aries issue with Hibernate](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARIES-1160).

I would still love to know if someone knows why transactions work with Hibernate and not with OpenJPA and if there is some configuration which allows me to use transactions with OpenJPA as well.